# jquery infinite random image fader

Tags: jquery, random, callback, queue, fadein

sadly i am totally new to jquery-writing and after googling for 12 hours to find a solution for my needs im giving up and ask straight away.

i am trying to write a short script, that fades in a random picture, delays a bit and then fades out. after that, the function should be invoked to infinity.

for now i mostly had the problem to accomplish the callback in such a manner, that its not regressing heavily but calling over and over. most scripts ive found let my firebug go crazy. also, i did not yet quite understood, how i can queue up the random image selector, a bit of attr (so its not always showing up at the exact same spot, but alternating a bit - but that has low priority), fadein, delay, fadeout and then doing it all over.

if someone could help me there, i'd be very, very grateful. 
alex.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Where does the script get the image reference? Do you have an array of images, or is it loading them out of the DOM? Or some other method.

Comment: There are thousands of plugin for jquery that do this and even more examples. a simple plugin to try and break down and customise is bgstretcher. Good luck

Comment: thanks guys. @ jonathan: atm it's pretty much all the same to me, as long as it's working. ;)
@ ppumkin: i know, but i couldn't find an easy and unintrusive one, that fitted exactly my needs. i really wanted a script thats as slim as possible.

and wow, stack overflow is awesome! XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very easy to do in jQuery:

### jQuery

```
$('document').ready(function() {
   
    var nextImage = function() {
         $('#slideshow > img:random')
          .fadeIn(function() {
               $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(nextImage);
           })
    };
    
    nextImage();
});
```

Using the help of the [`:random jQuery filter selector`](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/) -- it's worth noting I've added this in because you said "random" -- but in fact you probably want the "next" image because on occasions it will select the same image as last time, or won't give even time to all images. In which case you can use http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/7BLnT/

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/JbrXd/

Comment: that was exactly what i wanted. and yeah, you are correct about the random thingy, but i don't want visitors to always see the exact same row of pictures.